# How to add twitter tweet functionality on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm following this [Site](http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/demo/A-customized-Tweet-Box/) which is a easy way to add a customised tweet box and button on my site and will help in update of post.

As per its functionality, once we write any messages in the textbox and click on tweet button we will get the twitter login pop up window, once we are authenticated our message will be posted on our twitter account wall.

But when i run this code, i'm getting the pop up window and once i provide my credentials the window closes but no message is posted in the twitter account. When i checked on my javascript console im getting error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with https://api.twitter.com/xd_receiver.html from frame with URL about:blank. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'http', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'https'. Protocols must match.

I dont know what this error means as my site through which im running the form is clorderdev2.uvacha.com

Below is my code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=YOURCONSUMERKEY&v=1"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.jtweetsanywhere-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jtweetsanywhere-de-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="jTweetsAnywhereSample"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#jTweetsAnywhereSample').jTweetsAnywhere({
showTweetBox:{
    counter: true,
    width: 380,
    height: 65,
    label: '<span style="color: #A4A4A4">What\'s happening?</span>',
    defaultContent: '#jTweetsAnywhere',
    onTweet: function(textTweet, htmlTweet){
        alert('You tweeted: ' + textTweet);
    }
}
});</script>
```

Comment: This is the exact error : Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://clorderdev2.uvacha.com/fbtwtpost.aspx#oauth_access_token=ot8DIwAAAAAXX6tQAAAAAOJOIwAAAAAAYj2+7auRA4kisFdaSurCAlSwv+k=2ENLwWkcQcgGMzvC061yhVSHW42a2cYnMPChznIJ from frame with URL https://api.twitter.com/xd_receiver.html. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.

Comment: this above error is coming for the working site also but it is working there, then why it is not working for me

Answer (score 3):

There's a better plugin to get `Twitter` tweets, and it's called `livetwitter`.
All the information you need is here:

https://github.com/elektronaut/jquery.livetwitter

Comment: This is to get all the tweets, but no option to post the tweet

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a script, somewhere, is trying to communicate between http:// and https:// protocols. For security reasons, JavaScript can't do that. This is most likely a bug in one of the libraries you're using.

I'd suggest using the [official twitter implementation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button), if that's a possible alternative.

Comment: No, i cannot use the tweet button as im using textbox and button for facebook wall post so same way i want to do for twitter.